# Change Angular's app favicon in runtime - using a service

Tags: javascript, angular

Angular has the [Title service](https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title) to change the document's title in runtime.
Is there any similar but for the document's favicon? I know I can handle this using good old 'vanilla' javascript, but I was wondering if there is a service for the Title, that could be one for the favicon. But I didn't find this in the docs.

Comment: I don't think Angular has an equivalent built-in service looking at their source code location where the `Title` service comes from: (https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/5.2.9/packages/platform-browser/src/browser)